# Rails why is my parent object not saving?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters, model-associations

I'm quite new to rails/programming/web development, and this is the error that I'm getting:

**ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (can't write unknown attribute `'shopping_list_id'`)**

I'm trying to save a shopping list object which is populated with *Item* objects after selecting specific *Meal* objects (with collection_check_box) and the associated *Ingredient* objects.

Looking through the localhost server logs, all the items are created correctly using the correct ingredients retrieved (and assigned to the current shopping list id) from the correct meal_ids - but when it comes to saving the actual shopping list I get the above error. Please see below for image of server log.

I've been stuck on this for a few days now and I've seen many posts with the same error but all seem to have quite different contexts to this issue.

Is it something to do with strong_parameters? Or are my associations wrong?

**In my meals index.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for :shopping_list, url: shopping_lists_path do |f| %>
  <%= collection_check_boxes :shopping_list, :meal_ids, Meal.all, :id, :name  do |b|%>
    <%= b.label class:"label-checkbox" do%>
       <%=b.check_box + b.text%>
    <%end%>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Create Shopping List" %>
<% end %>
```

**My shopping_lists_controller:**

```
def create

  @shopping_list = ShoppingList.new(shopping_list_params)

  @meals = Meal.where(id:[@shopping_list.meal_ids])
  @meals.map do |meal|
    meal.ingredients.map do |ingredient|
      @shopping_list.items.build(name: ingredient.name, quantity: ingredient.quantity, unit: ingredient.unit, shopping_list_id: @shopping_list.id)
    end
  end


  respond_to do |format|
    if @shopping_list.save
      format.html { redirect_to @shopping_list, notice: 'Shopping List was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @shopping_list }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @shopping_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end 

end
```

private

```
def set_shopping_list
  @shopping_list = ShoppingList.find(params[:id])
end


def shopping_list_params
  params.require(:shopping_list).permit(:name, {meal_ids: []})
end
```

**My ShoppingList Model:**

```
class ShoppingList < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items
  has_many :meals
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :meals
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
end
```

**My Item Model:**

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shopping_list
end
```

**My schema.rb:**

```
create_table "ingredients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "meal_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.float    "quantity"
    t.integer  "unit"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["meal_id"], name: "index_ingredients_on_meal_id"
  end

  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "shopping_list_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.float    "quantity"
    t.integer  "unit"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
    t.index ["shopping_list_id"], name: "index_items_on_shopping_list_id"
  end

  create_table "meals", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.string   "method"
    t.datetime "created_at",              null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",              null: false
    t.string   "meal_image_file_name"
    t.string   "meal_image_content_type"
    t.integer  "meal_image_file_size"
    t.datetime "meal_image_updated_at"
    t.integer  "diet"
  end

  create_table "shopping_lists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

[Image of server log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzHpP.png)

Comment: You're trying to build several items at once and save them.  Try iterating through all of the items you plan on saving with a call to the shopping_list association and this problem should go away.

Comment: Thanks @bkunzi01 ! I'm not sure I understand what you mean by '... with a call to the shopping_list association' though, are you able to provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `Meal` model has `belongs_to :shopping_list` but it doesn't have column `shopping_list_id`.

So when you run

```
ShoppingList.create(meal_ids: ['1'])
```

Rails tries to create `Meal` model and link it back to the `ShoppingList`, but it can't since there is no such attribute and error tells you that `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError`. To fix create a migration e.g.:

```
add_column :meals, :shopping_list_id, :integer
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `create` method of `shopping_lists_controller`, you are using a new instance of `shopping_list` and using the id of that instance to create `items`. Since the new instance is not saved to the db, it will not have `id`. So you cannot use `@shopping_list.id` while creating items.
So either change

```
@shopping_list = ShoppingList.new(shopping_list_params)
```

to

```
@shopping_list = ShoppingList.create(shopping_list_params)
```

or do

```
@shopping_list = ShoppingList.new(shopping_list_params)
@shopping_list.save
```

You may also want to destroy this object if any exception is raised.

Comment: Thanks @Sajin, but I still get the same error trying both of those methods. If you have a look at the server log image, the '@shopping_list' object's id is added to each '@item' object's shopping_list_id successfully, but the issue arises when the '@shopping_list' object tries to save to the db.

When I tried the '@shopping_list = ShoppingList.create(shopping_list_params)' solution, the error was brought up there and didn't get a chance to build items.

Comment: I checked the logs again, the items are definitely saving successfully and each _item_ object has the correct shopping_list_id assigned to it, but the _shopping_list_ object itself will not save, and doesn't have an id. Which is confusing me a lot!